# safe reading from a stream in a for loop using getline

Tags: c++

I want to read from a stream using `std::getline` inside a for loop.

The stream I mean is a class inherited from the `std::basic_iostream`.

```
std::string line;            
for(;;){
      try{
          std::getline( myStreamObj, line );
          if( line != "" ){
              std::cout << line << std::endl;
          }
      }
      catch( std::ios_base::failure& ex ){
          std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
      }
  }
```

I want also to check against other error conditions like

```
eofbit failbit badbit
```

But I am bit confused about it.

If some of the conditions settings these 3 flags is met is any exception thrown like `std::ios_base::failure`? How to handlse these 3 cases? Do I have to do checkings other ways?

Thanks
AFG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to capture the errors via exceptions you need to set it using ios::exception. Otherwise an exception will not be thrown. You can check out the documentation here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/exceptions/.

You can also explicitly call ios::fail(), ios::bad() or ios::eof(). Docs here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/

Answer (score 6):

The iostreams by default do not throw exceptions when errors occur. If you want to enable them:

```
cout.execeptions( std::ios::badbit );
```

would enable exceptions if badbit is set.

To enable them all:

```
cout.execeptions( std::ios::badbit 
                   | std::ios::eofbit 
                   | std::ios::failbit );
```

The exceptions thrown are of type:

```
std::ios_base::failure
```

which is derived from `std::exception`.

In general though, it is easier not to use execptions, but to use constructs like:

```
while( std::getline( myStreamObj, line ) ) {
   // process line
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I didn't know about this condition so it comes useful. Can I ask you one more small detail. Why exceptions are not a good choice here?

Comment: @Abruzzo Lots of reasons - slower, don't easily support resumption, need to write more code to handle the errors. And most people reading your code will expect exceptions *not* to be used in this area, so they will find the code harder to understand.